# Arbitrary threshold for sigmoid activation function for CNN binary classification?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, nlp

I am classifying sentiment of reviews - `0` or `1` - using `gensim` Doc2Vec and CNN in `Tensorflow 2.2.0`:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, 
                                input_length=maxlen, 
                                embeddings_initializer=Constant(embedding), trainable=False),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D(),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                    epochs=8,
                    validation_split=0.3,
                    batch_size=10)
```

I then make predictions and convert my sigmoid probability to `0` or `1` using `np.round()`:

```
predicted = model.predict(X_test)
predicted = np.round(predicted,1).astype(np.int32)
```

I get great results (~96% accuracy) indicating that the threshold of `0.5` is working as expected...

However, when I try to predict on a set of new data, the model seems to separate bad reviews from good ones but across approx `0.0`:

```
# Example sigmoid outputs for new test reviews:
good_review_1: 0.000052
good_review_2: 0.000098

bad_review_1: 0.112334
bad_review_2: 0.214934
```

Mind you, the model never saw `X_test` during training and it is able to predict just fine. It's only when I introduce a new set of review text strings, I run into incorrect predictions. For new reviews, the only preprocessing that I do before calling `model.predict()` is feeding them through the same tokenizer used for model training:

```
s = 'This is a sample bad review.'
tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(pd.Series(s))
s = pad_sequences(s, maxlen=maxlen, padding='pre', truncating='pre')

model.predict(s)
```

I've been trying to make sense of this conundrum but I'm making little progress. I ran into [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405473/does-a-neural-network-with-sigmoid-activation-use-thresholds/12406063#12406063) and it indicates

> Some sigmoid functions will have this at 0, while some will have it set to a different 'threshold'.

But this still doesn't explain why my model was able to predict on `np.round()`'s `0.5` threshold for `X_test` dataset (which the model never learned on) and then unable to predict on new dataset at the same `0.5` threshold...

Comment: Can you try with `model.predict(X_test).round()` and check if there is any difference between the outputs.

Answer (score 1):

There are few possible answers, depending on extra details OP probably won't provide since question was posted 3 years ago, but somebody might find this useful anyway.

> I get great results (~96% accuracy) indicating that the threshold of 0.5 is > working as expected...

Do u get 96% accuracy via validation during training? Or via predicting, rounding, and comparing to targets? U could try using [model.evaluate()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#evaluate).
Make sure u don't validate in one way, and inference(predict) in another way.

If everything's good on that front and u validate and predict using the same approach (could be tested, just look at the outputs using your training data, testing data, this "new data" u mentioned is problematic), maybe the "new data" just differs drastically, u could take a look at it.

Also, this rounding code could be problematic, esp if u get 96% accuracy via validation during fitting and "new confusing results" come from predicting after rounding (different approach).

```
predicted = np.round(predicted,1).astype(np.int32)
```

Not sure where u get predictions like "0.000052, 0.000098.." from, if "different approaches for validation and predicting" hypothesis is wrong, maybe it's really about the data, doesn't look like it's after rounding either, anyway, this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrgsH.png) contains example highlighting the way this rounding approach could cause problems.